# Create full longdate format from shortDateFormat

Tags: php, laravel

I have number like 9212265447 (man) or 8856145441 (woman), which means that first two digit is year 1992 or 1988, for man 3rd and 4th digits are following month of birth, but for woman 5 or 6 on third place is just information that it is woman. If woman is born from Jan-Sep has 5 from Oct - Dec has 6. 
7060208520 - 60 means born 1970 October 20th, 61 will November 62 December.
5th and 6th digit means day of birth.

9212265447 - 26.12.1992

8856145441 - 14.6.1988

I need these numbers transfer to date format DD.MM.YYYY in PHP, 
any recommendations how? or links what is the process of it?

Appreciate any help

Comment: That is confusing. I'd suggest finding a different way to store these numbers, since you'll have issues determining if it's a man or woman (unless you're using 05 for May instead of 5, and then difficulty parsing it.

Comment: 56 == June??? ?

Comment: @devpro I think that comes from "5 or 6 if it's a woman, where birth months from Jan-Sep are 5, Oct-Dec is 6". Very confusing.

Comment: @aynber: i recommend your suggestion to store data with proper format.

Comment: Do you know beforehand that 9212265447 is a record for male and 8856145441 for female?

Comment: it is the way how social security number is written in Czech or Slovakia, you know if 3rd and 4th digit is 05 is man born in May, if it is 55 it is woman born in May, if it is 60 woman born in October, 61 woman born November, 62 woman born in December, for man if will regular expression of month .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if google translate did everything ok and I understood what is written here - https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodn%C3%A9_%C4%8D%C3%ADslo the result can be done like this:

```
<?php
$man = "9212265447";
$woman = "8856145441";
$test = "7060208520";

function parse(string $socialNumber): \DateTime
{
    $year = 1900 + substr($socialNumber, 0, 2);
    $month = substr($socialNumber, 2, 2);
    if ($month >= 50) {
        $month -= 50;
    }
    $day = substr($socialNumber, 4, 2);

    return (new \DateTime())->setDate($year, $month, $day);
}

var_dump(parse($man));
var_dump(parse($woman));
var_dump(parse($test));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// $number = '9212265447';

private function getDateFromNumber($number){

    $regex = '/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/m';

    if(preg_match_all($regex, $number, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)){

        // $matches has 
        // array:1 [
        //   0 => array:5 [
        //     0 => "9212265447"
        //     1 => "92"
        //     2 => "12"
        //     3 => "26"
        //     4 => "5447"
        //   ]
        // ]

        $detail = $matches[0];
        $year = $detail[1];
        $month = (string)$detail[2];
        $date = $detail[3];

        if(in_array($month[0], [5,6])){
            // Women 
            $month = ($month[0] == 6) ?  $month + 9 : $month;
        }

        $date = $month . '-' . $date . '-' . $year;

        return Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    else{

        throw new \Exception('Invalid format');
    }
}
```